# checkbox doesnt have a value php

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to turn a input into a checkbox on my form. When checked I want the value to be 1 and unchecked to be zero. I tried a few things but on submit the value doesnt get added into the db.

HTML-1:

```
<div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-push-1 form-group required">
                        <label class="control-label" for="input-active"><?php echo $entry_active; ?></label>
                          <div class="input-active required">
                          <input type="checkbox" name="active" value="0" placeholder="<?php echo $text_active; ?>" id="input-active" class="form-control"   />
                        </div>
                        <?php if (isset($error_date_starting)) { ?>
                          <label class="text-danger"><?php echo $error_code; ?></label>
                        <?php } ?>
                      </div>ut type="checkbox" name="active" value="0" placeholder="<?php echo $text_active; ?>" id="input-active" class="form-control"   />
                        </div>
                        <?php if (isset($error_date_starting)) { ?>
                          <label class="text-danger"><?php echo $error_code; ?></label>
                        <?php } ?>
                      </div>
```

HTML-2:

```
<div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-push-1 form-group required">
                        <label class="control-label" for="input-active"><?php echo $entry_active; ?></label>
                          <div class="input-active required">
                          <input type="hidden" name='active' value='0' placeholder="<?php echo $text_active; ?>" id="input-active" class="form-control"   />
                          <input type="checkbox" name='active' value='1' placeholder="<?php echo $text_active; ?>" id="input-active" class="form-control"   />
                        </div>
                        <?php if (isset($error_date_starting)) { ?>
                          <label class="text-danger"><?php echo $error_code; ?></label>
                        <?php } ?>
                      </div>
```

I tried a few Javascripts solutions but none worked:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#input-active').on('change', function(){
   this.value = this.checked ? 1 : 0;
   // alert(this.value);
}).change();
</script>
```

UPDATE!!
Still not working I've changed code following suggestions still not doing what I'd like.

New HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-push-1 form-group required">
                        <label class="control-label" for="input-active"><?php echo $entry_active; ?></label>
                          <div class="input-active required">

                          <input type="checkbox" name='active' value='0' placeholder="<?php echo $text_active; ?>" id="input-active" class="form-control"   />
                        </div>
                        <?php if (isset($error_date_starting)) { ?>
                          <label class="text-danger"><?php echo $error_code; ?></label>
                        <?php } ?>
                      </div>
```

New JS:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#input-active").change(function() {
      if(this.checked) {
          $("#input-active").val('1');
      } else {
          $("#input-active").val('0');
          }
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: IDs have to be unique. In your second HTML you have two elements with the same ID, and in both examples you have two elements with the same name. Since you're using PHP, the value of the second element will always override the first one of the same name.

Comment: I updated try this now

Comment: thanks for your help but still not working. I am using the script you put up. Do I need to change the html for this? What Im using currently is posted as  New HTML.

Comment: let me try this html for you

Comment: which version of jQuery are you using

Comment: Im working in Opencart and the Jquery  version is 2.1.1

Comment: I added the snippet you can check that
If you are supposing to re render your PHP believe me it will not, value is updating you can check console.

Comment: When a checkbox is checked, the value will be the one specified in the input tag. When it's not checked, the checkbox won't be included in the submit. So you can give the checkbox the value of 1, and in your PHP script check if the value (`$_POST['active']`) exists. If it doesn't, you know the checkbox wasn't checked so you manually assign it the value of zero, and if it does, it'll have whatever value you specified (In this case, 1).

Answer (score 0):

To catch the toggled event on input type please use the following function

```js
$("#input-active").change(function() {
  if($(this).is(':checked')) {
    console.log('checked')
    $(this).val(1);
  } else {
    console.log('un checked')
    $(this).val(0);
  }
  
  console.log($(this).val())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-push-1 form-group required">
  <label class="control-label" for="input-active">In active</label>
    <div class="input-active required">

    <input type="checkbox" name='active' value='0' placeholder="Active" id="input-active" class="form-control"   />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: I added some brief as much I feel suitable for this, will try to improve in future.

Comment: Improve in future by improving now.

Comment: can you help me with this ? mean how can I improve this.

Comment: A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: @Anon_guy, you can also use 

if($(this).is(':checked')) {}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155280/discussion-between-moeen-basra-and-jay-blanchard).

Comment: Ok so you are right I tried your script and followed along in console. So When I check the checkbox it does change the value to 1, why does it not store that value on submit?